# data not passing from CSV to MySQL query in Python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am trying to transfer data from a CSV file to a MySQL table, however at runtime I am getting the error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` Which I 'think' means the data isnt passing from the CSV into the query. This is the query I am using,

```
with open('data_final.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO countries(id, name, sport, Surname, height) "
                   "VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", row)
```

I know that %s is the old style,and hence frowned upon, and {} is the new style but I am unsure of how to incorporate it into the query with a `.format()`.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: How many columns have your rows?

Comment: 5 columns across the csv file, no irregular data

Comment: Give us the first few lines of your CSV file. If there is personal data there, change the data, but don't affect the structure (or any special characters that may be in there).

Comment: If you make a new CSV file that contains `100,n,s,s,50\n`(and only those characters), does it work?

Comment: Ah, i think you might have stumbled on the problem. Incorporating daniels suggestion and using a csv file of `100,n,s,s,50\n` the code works. I think that means there will be errors later in the data, I'll have to clean it, Thanks